# Apache 2 configtest failed: File name too long

Tags: apache2, apache2.4

I run an apache2 webserver locally on a raspberry-pi with raspbian distro.

It worked without a problem until suddenly it can't be started anymore with
`sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start`, which yields the following error:

> [....] Starting apache2 (via systemctl): apache2.serviceJob for
>   apache2.service failed. See 'systemctl status apache2.service' and
>   'journalctl -xn' for details.  failed!

Removing and reinstalling with apt-get doesn't solve it.systemctl status shows the following entries:

```
> Apr 22 11:27:16 raspberrypi apache2[18234]: [344B blob data] Apr 22
> 11:27:16 raspberrypi apache2[18234]: [293B blob data] Apr 22 11:27:16
> raspberrypi apache2[18234]: [293B blob data] Apr 22 11:27:16
> raspberrypi apache2[18234]: [293B blob data] Apr 22 11:27:16
> raspberrypi apache2[18234]: [293B blob data] Apr 22 11:27:16
> raspberrypi apache2[18234]: Action 'configtest' failed. Apr 22
> 11:27:16 raspberrypi apache2[18234]: The Apache error log may have
> more information. Apr 22 11:27:16 raspberrypi systemd[1]:
> apache2.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1 Apr 22
> 11:27:16 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Apache2 web
> server. Apr 22 11:27:16 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Unit apache2.service
> entered failed state.
```

journalctl -xn yields:

```
> -- Logs begin at Sun 2017-04-23 07:06:12 UTC, end at Sun 2017-04-23 12:38:48 UTC. -- Apr 23 12:38:30 raspberrypi apache2[3292]: [2.0K blob
> data] Apr 23 12:38:30 raspberrypi apache2[3292]: [1.7K blob data] Apr
> 23 12:38:30 raspberrypi apache2[3292]: Action 'configtest' failed. Apr
> 23 12:38:30 raspberrypi apache2[3292]: The Apache error log may have
> more information. Apr 23 12:38:31 raspberrypi systemd[1]:
> apache2.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1 Apr 23
> 12:38:31 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Apache2 web
> server.
> -- Subject: Unit apache2.service has failed
> -- Defined-By: systemd
> -- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
> --
> -- Unit apache2.service has failed.
> --
> -- The result is failed. Apr 23 12:38:31 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Unit apache2.service entered failed state. Apr 23 12:38:31 raspberrypi
> sudo[3278]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root Apr
> 23 12:38:48 raspberrypi sudo[3345]: pi : TTY=pts/0 ;
> PWD=/etc/apache2/conf-enabled ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/journalctl
> -xn Apr 23 12:38:48 raspberrypi sudo[3345]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by pi(uid=0)
```

Unfortunately the apache error.log contains no useful information whatsoever. But if i run apache2 configtest I get a "File name too long" error.

Strangely even after formatting my sdcard and putting a fresh copy of the distribution image on it and reinstalling apache2 the error remains.

What can I do?

Comment: Look for a long filename in the configuration - shorten it

Comment: @Ed Heal: I can't find no filenames in the apache2.conf. Is this the wrong conf to look at?

Comment: does apachectl -t report something better?

Comment: no... it reports: File name too long
Action '-t' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information. But the error log only has [Sun Apr 23 05:47:59.265137 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 9002:tid 1995509760] AH00489: Apache/2.4.10 (Raspbian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Apr 23 05:47:59.265211 2017] [core:notice] [pid 9002:tid 1995509760] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sun Apr 23 05:49:23.895892 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 9002:tid 1995509760] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down

Comment: btw current timestamp is Mon Apr 24 02:44:51 UTC 2017